# How to set an ImageView to Visible based on a button click in android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to show an imageView inside a scroll wheel, but I want the imageView to be visible only when a button is clicked. If the button is not clicked the image shouldn't be displayed. I tried a lot of possible ways to work out the problem but can't figure out why the app keeps crashing when I click on the button that is responsible for setting the image to visible. A little help would be appreciated. Thank you

Below is my Chapter1.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Chapter1"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/Chp1_button1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Go to Main Menu"
       android:padding="20dp"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Chp1_button1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap11_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Chap 1.1 Definition" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap12_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Chap 1.2 Explanation" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap13_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Chap 1.3 Hello World" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/chap14_btn"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Chap 1.4 Hello World" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tableLayout1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id = "@+id/image_Layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/a951ad1201c7bd1a758b5acfeea33fce_0"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Chp2_button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to End"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Chapter1.java file

```
package com.example.mathprojectraoli;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Chapter1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter1);
        Button[] menuBtns = {findViewById(R.id.Chp1_button1), findViewById(R.id.Chp2_button2)};
        Button[] btns = {findViewById(R.id.chap11_btn), findViewById(R.id.chap12_btn), findViewById(R.id.chap13_btn), findViewById(R.id.chap14_btn)};
        String[] activityNames = {"com.example.mathprojectraoli.MainActivity","com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter16"};
        int[] imageIds = {
                R.drawable.a951ad1201c7bd1a758b5acfeea33fce_0,
                R.drawable.a951ad1201c7bd1a758b5acfeea33fce_1,
                R.drawable.a951ad1201c7bd1a758b5acfeea33fce_2,
                R.drawable.a951ad1201c7bd1a758b5acfeea33fce_3};
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.image_Layout);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        for(int i = 0; i < menuBtns.length; i++)
        {
            final String activityName = activityNames[i];
            menuBtns[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName(activityName));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        btns[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried running this code but when I try to click the button chapter1.1 Definition the app stops working without giving out any errors. I'm confused where is the code going wrong. Some help would be appreciated.